# Admin Create/Invite New User with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, inheritance, methods

I have a simple rails app using devise--as such (and being a new rails guy), some of these methods are super classed and inherited, I think...

How can I create a few methods in my brand new admin controller to 1) Make a new user and 2) edit current users?

I feel that the typical CRUD operations will make a lot of redundant code and I would like to use some rails best practices to simply allow admins to edit multiple profiles (where users can only edit their own) and also add...

Again, I'm new to rails, so speak slowly. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The devise wiki has everything you need to configure/customise devise https://github.com/plataformatec/devise, I know that's not the exact answer but its a good place to start.

have you looked at active admin? http://activeadmin.info/  Works well with devise and gets you up and running with an administration framework very quickly